# Vertical scrollbar in a disabled textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

I have a disabled textarea control which is dynamically updated, but the vertical scrollbar doesn't appear in this case.  How should I fix it?

```
.clsTextArea{
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

<textarea class="clsTextArea" disabled></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
.clsTextArea {
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It definitely works to display the scrollbar, perhaps you have conflicting CSS properties overriding this? Example of this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gfmedv4k/

Comment: This is all the class.  Maybe there is a conflict with other properties:

.clsTextArea{
    width: 96%;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: I have just checked my coding at jsfiddle.net and it works!  So it seems to be a problem about my hosting provider or navigator cache...

Comment: Yes, it worked!  It was a cache problem.  Thank you!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

add overflow-y :scroll ;

```css
.clsTextArea {
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="clsTextArea" disabled></textarea>
```